# How get feedback from APNs when sending push notification

Tags: ios6, push-notification, push, feedback, passbook

Now I can send push Token from device that has installed a pass already, but I don't know how the feedback work in this point. From apple docs, Apple Push Notification service (APNs) provides feedback to server to tell if pushToken is valid or not. How to get this feedback ? I try this code, but a lot errors. This is the code:

```
<?php
$cert = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/certificates.pem';
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $cert);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);

$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196', $error,            $errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
// production server is ssl://feedback.push.apple.com:2196

if (!$fp) {
error_log("Failed to connect feedback server: $err $errstr",0);
return;
}
else {
   error_log("Connection to feedback server OK",0);
}
    error_log("APNS feedback results",0);
    while ($devcon = fread($fp, 38))
    {
   $arr = unpack("H*", $devcon); 
   $rawhex = trim(implode("", $arr));
   $feedbackTime = hexdec(substr($rawhex, 0, 8)); 
   $feedbackDate = date('Y-m-d H:i', $feedbackTime); 
   $feedbackLen = hexdec(substr($rawhex, 8, 4)); 
   $feedbackDeviceToken = substr($rawhex, 12, 64);
   error_log ("TIMESTAMP:" . $feedbackDate, 0);
      error_log ( "DEVICE ID:" . $feedbackDeviceToken,0);
    }
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work.  You don't need to run this with every push request.  Depending on how frequently you update, and the number of devices, you could set a daily or weekly cron job.

```
$cert_file = '/path/to/combined/cert.pem';
$cert_pw = 'top secret';

$stream_context = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($stream_context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $cert_file);
if (strlen($cert_pw))
    stream_context_set_option($stream_context, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $cert_pw);

$apns_connection = stream_socket_client('feedback.push.apple.com:2196', $error_code, $error_message, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $stream_context);

if($apns_connection === false) {
    apns_close_connection($apns_connection);

    error_log ("APNS Feedback Request Error: $error_code - $error_message", 0);
}

$feedback_tokens = array();

while(!feof($apns_connection)) {
    $data = fread($apns_connection, 38);
    if(strlen($data)) {
        $feedback_tokens[] = unpack("N1timestamp/n1length/H*devtoken", $data);
    }
}
fclose($apns_connection);


if (count($feedback_tokens))
    foreach ($feedback_tokens as $k => $token) {
         // code to delete record from database
    }
```

Comment: Just ti be sure if I have well understood, the code you wrote returns an array of tokens which aren't valid anymore right? Then it's my job to delete then from mysql...